# Finding the masses of the vertices of a triangle given the barycenter

Tags: geometry

Given a triangle A(−3,−1) B(3,2) C(4,−3) and a point P(1,0) inside it. Find the masses to be placed at the vertices of the triangle such that P will be the barycenter of the triangle.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. 
In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you write what your thoughts 
are on the problem and include your efforts (work in progress) in this and future posts 
and in what context you have encountered the problem; this will prevent people 
from telling you things you already know, 
and help them give their answers at the right level. This site uses 
[MathJax formatting](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation)

Comment: The problem is under-specified; if $(m_A,m_B,m_C)$ is a solution, then so is $(km_A,km_B,km_C)$ for any $k > 0$. So you have to start by assuming a particular value for one of the masses, for instance $m_A=1$.

Comment: What does barycentre mean?

Comment: @Nikunj: Centre of mass.

Comment: Hint: place masses m1, m2, and m3 at the 3 vertices and see where the barycenter is (as a function of m1, m2, m3). Compute what values for m1, m2, m3 you need to make the barycenter equal to (1,0). As @TonyK notes, there is an entire family of such values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The diagram illustrates the question statement.
[image]

Equilibrium along the x axis results the first equation:
$4m_1=2m_2+3m_3$

Equilibrium along the y axis results the second equation:
$2m_2= m_1+3m_3$

Having three unknowns and only two equations means multitude of triplet solutions. 
Solve for $m_1=1$

I will leave it from here for you to continue...

Comment: Thank you! For the y axis results why aren't the coefficients -1 and -3?

Comment: I actually made a mistake in the equations. I will edit them.

Comment: You multiply by distance from P. Do you accept the solution?

Comment: Yes thank you, I have those distances already so I will give those equations a try

Comment: You need to click the acceptance button...:)